# Multiple Documents Web Parts on same Master Site?

Tags: document-library

I am trying to create a subjectShare area for work. I have created a master site called "SubjectShare" and within there two sub-pages called Science and Art. I have added the Documents Web part so they can store their files on there, but both of the document parts are connected which dont want.

Is there any way where within the same master site, there can be multiple/different document parts so they can only see the files they uploaded and want to see instead of other departments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for two storage places correct? Creating a new document library creates a new storage area. This second document library may then be added as a webpart.

Comment: Hi, yes that is correct I am looking for two storage locations. Currently I have: http://i.imgur.com/cifHSvU.png  and just adding the same one on two different pages, but the actual storage location is the same.

Would I need to create another document library web part then add that to the page?

Comment: Ahh thank you :) - Found out how to do it.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer. Glad you found out anyway. If this is the complete answer to your question please mark it as answered.